# create and insert html elements dynamically into the DOM that recreate the student's picture

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

I am unable to get the array of images to display within the "pic-grid" div with javascript.

I am trying to display them at the load of the page and to do them dynamically with javascript, also not using innerHTML.

I can get the divs to display within the "pic-grid" div but not the image.

I have tried:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
            var newImage = document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

            newImage.src = personArray[i].url;

            newImage.setAttribute('class','frame');

            newImage.setAttribute('onclick','promptForName(this)');

            newImage.setAttribute('onmouseover','styleIt(this)');

            newImage.setAttribute('onmouseout','unStyleIt(this)');

        }
```

also

```
        var newImage = document.createElement('div');

        newImage.setAttribute('src', personArray.url);

        newImage.setAttribute('class','frame');

        newImage.setAttribute('onclick','promptForName(this)');

        newImage.setAttribute('onmouseover','styleIt(this)');

        newImage.setAttribute('onmouseout','unStyleIt(this)');

        document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(newImage);
```

and a variety of other code that I unfortunately did not keep/document.

I just need to be able to get the images from the "personArray" variable by the url to each of the divs that get created within the "populateImages" function.

```
    var currentId = "";
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    var personArray = [{
        firstname: "Bluto",
        url: "https://lfernandez.org/web1430/pics/bluto.jpg"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Abarnave",
        url: "https://lfernandez.org/web1430/pics/abarnave.jpg"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Chris",
        url: "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00NGJGHQ.JPG"           
    }
    ,
    {
        firstname: "Bryson", 
        url: "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00MA8QNC.JPG"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Cory", 
        url: "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00NSXJBT.JPG"
    }
    ,
    {
        firstname: "Ella", 
        url: "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00N4V0E7.JPG"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Sydnie", 
        url: "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00OCFIPQ.JPG"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Derek", 
        url: "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00P7UMKW.JPG"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Ryan", 
        url: "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00N5N0QA.JPG"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Sarah", 
        url: "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00NA065B.JPG"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Spencer", 
        url: "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00OSZTOL.JPG"
    }
    ];


    function populateImages() {
        //Note to student: You have to write the contents of this method!

        for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
            var newImage = document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

            newImage.src = personArray[i].url;

            newImage.setAttribute('class','frame');

            newImage.setAttribute('onclick','promptForName(this)');

            newImage.setAttribute('onmouseover','styleIt(this)');

            newImage.setAttribute('onmouseout','unStyleIt(this)');

        }          

    }
```

Comment: Didn't read thoroughly, but do you want to create a div or a img element? Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Glad you asked, I forgot to mention that I have tried creating an img element as well and just get a blank square.

Comment: @CoryColeman Not sure what went wrong, your code works fine when I change the elemented created from div to img. Please see my answer.

Comment: so I tried creating img again and somehow got the images this time, but I need to have it create a div with the createElement and then get the images to show in those divs. what is best to do in that situation?

Comment: @CoryColeman create one div dynamically that wraps all images or create a div for every image (and add class frame to these divs as well I assume)?

Comment: @CoryColeman added a div only solution using the images as a `background-image`, as well as a div with a nested img solution, see my updated answer.

Comment: so with "var newImage = document.createElement('div');" how can i get it to place one of the images into that created div?

Comment: I tried doing  - newImage.src = "https://portalapps.weber.edu/wcpictures/00OSZTOL.JPG"; but i just get a blank square

Comment: Sorry just saw that you updated your answer. yes that works much better and hopefully further in the right direction. I'll obviously have to mess with my stylings and such. Thank you a bunch

Comment: @CoryColeman feel free to accept it as an answer if it resolved your problem. You are also free to post your own answer containing your final solution and accept that one (See:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Glad I could help out :)

Comment: The following answer resolved my issue of images not showing up:

function populateImages() {
  //Note to student: You have to write the contents of this method!

  for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
    var imageContainer = document.createElement("div");
    var image = document.createElement("img")
    
    imageContainer.classList.add('frame');
    image.src = personArray[i].url;
    
    imageContainer.appendChild(image);
    document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(imageContainer);

  }

}

Comment: Please don't use the comment section for this, this is not very clear for anyone coming across your question in the future. Use the answer system instead. From the help page I linked (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."